# Jenkins emailext not sending mails

Tags: email, jenkins, groovy, email-ext

I am currently trying to understand why Jenkins is not sending emails.
The expected behavior is, that Jenkins will send emails to the whole team if the master branch is broken. If a feature branch breaks a email to the person who broke it, should be send.

Emails for the master branch are working, but not for broken feature branches.We are using the [email-ext](http://%20https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/) plugin. If you take a look at the code below you will see that the `getEMailRecipients` function will return an empty string for feature branches.

---

### Docs example

In the docs an [example](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Recipes) is given that should

> Send an email to abc plus any addresses returned by the providers

```
emailext (
           body: 'A Test EMail', 
           recipientProviders: [
                                 [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],
                                 [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']
                               ], 
           subject: 'Test', 
           to: 'abc'
         )
```

My understanding of this example is, that an email should be send even if the `to` property is empty.

---

### Property value docs

The docs for the plugin state the following for the `'CulpritsRecipientProvider'` option

> Sends email to the list of users who committed a change since the last
>   non-broken build till now. This list at least always include people
>   who made changes in this build, but if the previous build was a
>   failure it also includes the culprit list from there.

---

### My Code

**Helper functions:**

```
def getTeamRecipients() {
    return 'name1 name2 nameX'
}


def getEMailRecipients(currentBranch) {
    return (currentBranch.toLowerCase().contains("current") ||
            currentBranch.toLowerCase().contains("master")) ?
           getTeamRecipients() :
           ""
}


def sendEMail(recipients) {
    emailext (
        to: recipients,
        subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME}' is in state ${currentBuild.currentResult}",
        body: "See ${env.BUILD_URL} for more details",
        recipientProviders: [
            [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
        ]
    )
}
```

**Email Send part:**

```
 if (currentBuild.currentResult == "FAILURE") {
        def recipients = getEMailRecipients("$BRANCH_NAME")
        sendEMail(recipients)
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with my build script code?

Comment: In the `getTeamRecipients` function, you are writing your own code to return names. why? Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30229747/5003256) instead.

Comment: And as per the official `Email Ext Plugin`, versions below `2.57` will not send emails to outside because of security. So please update your plugin if needed. [Check here - 2.57.1 (March 20, 2017)](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).